# Json Parsing using Glue

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have to load Json files which are available in S3 to redshift tables. The schema/keys in json file are not consistent and not defined, but the final table schema is defined. Could anyone provide an efficient solution to address this. I can use python or pyspark for coding.